# My switch statement seem to return a value but does not take it all the way up to the function it self

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Im nesting a switch statement within a switch statement nested in a function which is supposed to return a a value to be used in a future builder but for some reason buy use of a debugger i notice that the value returned from the switch statement does not get all the way to return statement of the function.... Ive done a lot of research but none of them seem to point out my problem...

```
_switchFunction(List<String> runningShow) {
Timer.periodic(
  Duration(seconds: 10),
  (Timer t) {
    int timeHour = DateTime.now().hour;
    int timeDay = DateTime.now().weekday;
    String workingUrl = '';
    // day checker switch function
    switch (timeDay) {
      case (1):
      case (2):
      case (3):
      case (4):
      case (5):
        // hour checker switch function
        switch (timeHour) {
          case (0):
          case (1):
          case (2):
          case (3):
          case (4):
          case (5):
          case (6):
          case (7):
          case (8):
          case (9):
            return workingUrl = runningShow[0];
          case (10):
          case (11):
          case (12):
          case (13):
          case (14):
            return workingUrl = runningShow[1];
          case (16):
          case (17):
          case (18):
            return workingUrl = runningShow[2];
          case (19):
          case (20):
          case (21):
          case (22):
          case (23):
            return workingUrl = runningShow[3];
          default:
            break;
        }
        break;
      case (6):
        if (timeHour >= 14 && timeHour <= 20) {
          return workingUrl = runningShow[4];
        } else {
          return Image.asset(
            'assets/default.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
          );
        }
        break;
      case (7):
        return Image.asset(
          'assets/default.jpg',
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
        );
        break;
      default:
    }
    print(workingUrl);
    return workingUrl;
  },
);}
```

I still get this error after the comments..

```
Restarted application in 2,320ms.
I/flutter ( 5052): AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null)
I/flutter ( 5052): AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>>(ConnectionState.done, [https://i.postimg.cc/NjZGz6fS/Studio-Screens-Wake-01.png, https://i.postimg.cc/Gtbmjbhp/Studio-Screens-Mid-01.png, https://i.postimg.cc/4x0nTCw8/Studio-Screens-Drive-01.png, https://i.postimg.cc/RZhq8C16/Studio-Screens-Maloko-01.png], null)
I/flutter ( 5052): Fetched Urls are:[https://i.postimg.cc/NjZGz6fS/Studio-Screens-Wake-01.png, https://i.postimg.cc/Gtbmjbhp/Studio-Screens-Mid-01.png, https://i.postimg.cc/4x0nTCw8/Studio-Screens-Drive-01.png, https://i.postimg.cc/RZhq8C16/Studio-Screens-Maloko-01.png]
I/flutter ( 5052): this is null

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///null

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _HttpClient._openUrl  (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2187:9)
#1      _HttpClient.getUrl  (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2118:48)
#2      NetworkImage._loadAsync 
package:flutter/…/painting/_network_image_io.dart:84
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      NetworkImage.load 
package:flutter/…/painting/_network_image_io.dart:48
...
Image provider: NetworkImage("null", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("null", scale: 1.0)
═══
```

Comment: The return statement does not apply to the switch statement. When you run the return statement from within the switch statement you are returning from the encompassing function itself. Remove the return statements from the switch clause, but keep the assignments, and add breaks after each and every one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a `Timer.periodic` here. If you want to repeatedly update your screen, you will have to repeatedly call `setState() {}` or a similar approach anyways. 
If you simplify your code like below, it is more obvious you do indeed not return anything:

```
_switchFunction(List<String> runningShow) {
Timer.periodic(
   Duration(seconds: 10),
   (Timer t) {
      int timeHour = DateTime.now().hour;
      int timeDay = DateTime.now().weekday;
      String workingUrl = '';
      switch(timeDay) { 
         case 1: 
            workingURL = 'foo';
            return workingURL;
            break;
         default: 
            break;
      }
 }); // End of Timer.periodic
 // We could do quite a lot of stuff here.
 // for examply, we could return just something random: 
 return 'foo';
 }
```

However, with the following snippet, it will work:

```
_switchFunction(List<String> runningShow) {
      int timeHour = DateTime.now().hour;
      int timeDay = DateTime.now().weekday;
      String workingUrl = '';
      switch(timeDay) { 
         case 1: 
            workingURL = 'foo';
            return workingURL;
            break;
         default: 
            break;
      }
 }
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how set state will constantly check the time and update the url?

Comment: I did not mean that setState will constantly check the time. I just assumed that by constantly updating your URL, you want to constantly update your screen. Usually, you do not need to update a variable if you don't need it. If you need the URL at any given time, you simply run the function at that moment. The function will than return the correct URL.